# Can't figure out how to fix a word replace javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change some words on a page with the below script. I m not sure how to fix it ... can anybody help?

http://jsfiddle.net/cip691/yUMS7/

```
var dict = {
    "not": " NOT ",
    "is not": " IS NOT ",
    "like": " likeeee ",
    "Like": "lllike",
    "job": "JOB"
},
    terms = [],
    term;
for (term in dict) { terms.push(term);
var search = new RegExp('\\b(' + terms.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
                };
// now for every text node:
textNode.data = textNode.data.replace(search, function(full, match) {
    return dict[match] || match;
});​
```

Comment: I think it's better if you describe the purpose of your script as well, because it's slightly confusing and there might be easier ways for the same thing

Comment: I just want to replace words on a page with already defined words of my own. I have something that does this, but from what I understand this will not change "notification" to "NOTification"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define `textNode`

like in this example

[link example](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkuedch.php)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetTextNode () {
            var textContainer = document.getElementById ("textContainer");
            var textNode = textContainer.firstChild;
            alert (textNode.data);
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="textContainer">This is a simple text in the container.</div>
    <button onclick="GetTextNode ()">Get the contents of the container</button>
</body>
```